# How can you create this shape in Swift?

Tags: swift, shapes, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I tried to create this very unique shape in swift a long time ago but failed. My goal is to draw a shape like in this [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jF6Fr.jpg) (I mean the darker shape in that image).
How can you create such a unique shape in Swift?

Comment: I don't think that shape has any particular name, but it looks like a pretty straight forward bezier path. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

As Alexander says, it looks like that shape would be pretty easy to create using Bezier curves.

I'd suggest opening that image in a program like Photoshop that offers a Bezier path drawing tool and trying to recreate it there. Once you have the control points that get you the shape you are after, you can write down their coordinates and recreate them using a `UIBezierPath` in iOS.

A cubic bezier path has 2 end points and 2 middle control points. The curve moves from the starting point to the ending point, and gets pulled towards the first middle control point first, and then pulled towards the second control point. You can create a wide variety of curves that have 2 "humps" in them with a single Bezier curve, and you can chain multiple Bezier curves together to create more complex shapes. If you arrange the control points for connecting Bezier curves correctly you can get curves that transition smoothly from one to the next. With a different arrangement of the control points between Bezier curves, you can create sharp corners between curves.

I suggest you google Bezier curves, and do some experimenting.

I'm not particularly good with the path tool in Photoshop, but I got pretty close with a few minutes tinkering. here is a screen-shot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I´ll definitely try that out!